# Android Studio fails to create new project

Tags: android, android-studio

I'm getting started using Android Studio, and even after reinstalling the entire IDE a couple of times it's still not working right. When I create a new project, it loads with an error saying that the gradle wrapper properties could not load.

```
Could not load wrapper properties from '...MyApplication2\gradle\wrapper\gradle-wrapper.properties'.
```

The contents of that file, on the newly created project mind you, are this:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project version="4">
<component name="AndroidLayouts">
<shared>
<config />
</shared>
</component>
<component name="AndroidLogFilters">
<
```

Exactly that, with the unmatched final bracket and all. And when creating a new project, the IDE throws this error message.

```
java.lang.RuntimeException: java.lang.NullPointerException
    at com.intellij.openapi.application.TransactionGuardImpl.submitTransactionAndWait(TransactionGuardImpl.java:174)
    at com.intellij.openapi.command.WriteCommandAction.execute(WriteCommandAction.java:234)
    at com.intellij.openapi.command.WriteCommandAction$BuilderImpl.compute(WriteCommandAction.java:122)
    at com.android.tools.idea.npw.module.ModuleModel$ModuleTemplateRenderer.render(ModuleModel.kt:125)
    at com.android.tools.idea.npw.model.MultiTemplateRenderer$countDown$2.invoke(MultiTemplateRenderer.kt:139)
    at com.android.tools.idea.npw.model.MultiTemplateRenderer$countDown$2.invoke(MultiTemplateRenderer.kt:42)
    at com.android.tools.idea.npw.model.NewProjectModel$multiTemplateRenderer$1$$special$$inlined$run$lambda$1$1.run(NewProjectModel.kt:124)
    at com.intellij.openapi.fileEditor.impl.NonProjectFileWritingAccessProvider.disableChecksDuring(NonProjectFileWritingAccessProvider.java:174)
    at com.android.tools.idea.npw.model.NewProjectModel$multiTemplateRenderer$1$$special$$inlined$run$lambda$1.invoke(NewProjectModel.kt:123)
    at com.android.tools.idea.npw.model.NewProjectModel$multiTemplateRenderer$1$$special$$inlined$run$lambda$1.invoke(NewProjectModel.kt:103)
    at com.android.tools.idea.gradle.project.AndroidNewProjectInitializationStartupActivity.runActivity(AndroidNewProjectInitializationStartupActivity.kt:41)
    at com.intellij.ide.startup.impl.StartupManagerImpl.runActivity(StartupManagerImpl.java:216)
    at com.intellij.ide.startup.impl.StartupManagerImpl.lambda$runPostStartupActivitiesFromExtensions$2(StartupManagerImpl.java:168)
    at com.intellij.openapi.extensions.impl.ExtensionPointImpl.processWithPluginDescriptor(ExtensionPointImpl.java:292)
    at com.intellij.openapi.extensions.ExtensionPointName.processWithPluginDescriptor(ExtensionPointName.java:157)
    at com.intellij.ide.startup.impl.StartupManagerImpl.runPostStartupActivitiesFromExtensions(StartupManagerImpl.java:166)
    at com.intellij.openapi.project.impl.ProjectManagerImpl.doLoadProject(ProjectManagerImpl.java:461)
    at com.intellij.openapi.project.impl.ProjectManagerImpl.lambda$loadProjectUnderProgress$8(ProjectManagerImpl.java:440)
    at com.intellij.openapi.progress.impl.CoreProgressManager$2.run(CoreProgressManager.java:247)
    at com.intellij.openapi.progress.impl.CoreProgressManager$TaskRunnable.run(CoreProgressManager.java:888)
    at com.intellij.openapi.progress.impl.CoreProgressManager$5.run(CoreProgressManager.java:441)
    at com.intellij.openapi.progress.impl.CoreProgressManager.lambda$runProcess$2(CoreProgressManager.java:163)
    at com.intellij.openapi.progress.impl.CoreProgressManager.registerIndicatorAndRun(CoreProgressManager.java:585)
    at com.intellij.openapi.progress.impl.CoreProgressManager.executeProcessUnderProgress(CoreProgressManager.java:531)
    at com.intellij.openapi.progress.impl.ProgressManagerImpl.executeProcessUnderProgress(ProgressManagerImpl.java:59)
    at com.intellij.openapi.progress.impl.CoreProgressManager.runProcess(CoreProgressManager.java:150)
    at com.intellij.openapi.application.impl.ApplicationImpl.lambda$null$4(ApplicationImpl.java:441)
    at com.intellij.util.ConcurrencyUtil.runUnderThreadName(ConcurrencyUtil.java:221)
    at com.intellij.util.ConcurrencyUtil.lambda$underThreadNameRunnable$3(ConcurrencyUtil.java:209)
    at com.intellij.openapi.application.impl.ApplicationImpl$1.run(ApplicationImpl.java:238)
    at java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Executors.java:511)
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:266)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1149)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:624)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748)
Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException
    at com.intellij.xml.arrangement.XmlArrangementVisitor.createNewEntry(XmlArrangementVisitor.java:100)
    at com.intellij.xml.arrangement.XmlArrangementVisitor.visitXmlTag(XmlArrangementVisitor.java:52)
    at com.intellij.psi.impl.source.xml.XmlTagImpl.accept(XmlTagImpl.java:310)
    at com.intellij.xml.arrangement.XmlArrangementVisitor.visitXmlFile(XmlArrangementVisitor.java:45)
    at com.intellij.psi.impl.source.xml.XmlFileImpl.accept(XmlFileImpl.java:71)
    at com.intellij.xml.arrangement.XmlRearranger.parse(XmlRearranger.java:128)
    at com.intellij.psi.codeStyle.arrangement.engine.ArrangementEngine$Context.from(ArrangementEngine.java:550)
    at com.intellij.psi.codeStyle.arrangement.engine.ArrangementEngine.arrange(ArrangementEngine.java:119)
    at com.intellij.psi.codeStyle.arrangement.engine.ArrangementEngine.arrange(ArrangementEngine.java:83)
    at com.android.tools.idea.templates.TemplateUtils.reformatAndRearrange(TemplateUtils.kt:208)
    at com.android.tools.idea.templates.TemplateUtils.reformatAndRearrange$default(TemplateUtils.kt:184)
    at com.android.tools.idea.templates.TemplateUtils$reformatAndRearrange$1.run(TemplateUtils.kt:154)
    at com.intellij.openapi.command.WriteCommandAction.lambda$runWriteCommandAction$5(WriteCommandAction.java:356)
    at com.intellij.openapi.command.WriteCommandAction$BuilderImpl$1.run(WriteCommandAction.java:110)
    at com.intellij.openapi.application.RunResult.run(RunResult.java:35)
    at com.intellij.openapi.command.WriteCommandAction.lambda$null$1(WriteCommandAction.java:251)
    at com.intellij.openapi.application.impl.ApplicationImpl.runWriteAction(ApplicationImpl.java:885)
    at com.intellij.openapi.command.WriteCommandAction.lambda$performWriteCommandAction$2(WriteCommandAction.java:250)
    at com.intellij.openapi.command.WriteCommandAction.lambda$doExecuteCommand$4(WriteCommandAction.java:308)
    at com.intellij.openapi.command.impl.CoreCommandProcessor.executeCommand(CoreCommandProcessor.java:212)
    at com.intellij.openapi.command.impl.CoreCommandProcessor.executeCommand(CoreCommandProcessor.java:188)
    at com.intellij.openapi.command.WriteCommandAction.doExecuteCommand(WriteCommandAction.java:310)
    at com.intellij.openapi.command.WriteCommandAction.performWriteCommandAction(WriteCommandAction.java:249)
    at com.intellij.openapi.command.WriteCommandAction.execute(WriteCommandAction.java:230)
    at com.intellij.openapi.command.WriteCommandAction$BuilderImpl.run(WriteCommandAction.java:112)
    at com.intellij.openapi.command.WriteCommandAction.runWriteCommandAction(WriteCommandAction.java:356)
    at com.intellij.openapi.command.WriteCommandAction.runWriteCommandAction(WriteCommandAction.java:348)
    at com.android.tools.idea.templates.TemplateUtils.reformatAndRearrange(TemplateUtils.kt:146)
    at com.android.tools.idea.npw.model.NewTemplateRendererKt$render$2.run(NewTemplateRenderer.kt:65)
    at com.intellij.ide.startup.impl.StartupManagerImpl.lambda$runWhenProjectIsInitialized$6(StartupManagerImpl.java:486)
    at com.intellij.ui.GuiUtils.invokeLaterIfNeeded(GuiUtils.java:324)
    at com.intellij.ide.startup.impl.StartupManagerImpl.runWhenProjectIsInitialized(StartupManagerImpl.java:472)
    at com.android.tools.idea.npw.model.NewTemplateRendererKt.render(NewTemplateRenderer.kt:65)
    at com.android.tools.idea.npw.module.ModuleModel$ModuleTemplateRenderer.renderTemplate(ModuleModel.kt:152)
    at com.android.tools.idea.npw.module.ModuleModel$ModuleTemplateRenderer$render$success$1.compute(ModuleModel.kt:126)
    at com.android.tools.idea.npw.module.ModuleModel$ModuleTemplateRenderer$render$success$1.compute(ModuleModel.kt:77)
    at com.intellij.openapi.command.WriteCommandAction$BuilderImpl$2.run(WriteCommandAction.java:120)
    at com.intellij.openapi.application.RunResult.run(RunResult.java:35)
    at com.intellij.openapi.command.WriteCommandAction.lambda$null$1(WriteCommandAction.java:251)
    at com.intellij.openapi.application.impl.ApplicationImpl.runWriteAction(ApplicationImpl.java:885)
    at com.intellij.openapi.command.WriteCommandAction.lambda$performWriteCommandAction$2(WriteCommandAction.java:250)
    at com.intellij.openapi.command.WriteCommandAction.lambda$doExecuteCommand$4(WriteCommandAction.java:308)
    at com.intellij.openapi.command.impl.CoreCommandProcessor.executeCommand(CoreCommandProcessor.java:220)
    at com.intellij.openapi.command.impl.CoreCommandProcessor.executeCommand(CoreCommandProcessor.java:188)
    at com.intellij.openapi.command.WriteCommandAction.doExecuteCommand(WriteCommandAction.java:310)
    at com.intellij.openapi.command.WriteCommandAction.performWriteCommandAction(WriteCommandAction.java:249)
    at com.intellij.openapi.command.WriteCommandAction.lambda$execute$0(WriteCommandAction.java:234)
    at com.intellij.openapi.application.TransactionGuardImpl.lambda$submitTransactionAndWait$2(TransactionGuardImpl.java:162)
    at com.intellij.openapi.application.TransactionGuardImpl.runSyncTransaction(TransactionGuardImpl.java:83)
    at com.intellij.openapi.application.TransactionGuardImpl.lambda$submitTransaction$1(TransactionGuardImpl.java:107)
    at com.intellij.openapi.application.impl.LaterInvocator$FlushQueue.doRun(LaterInvocator.java:441)
    at com.intellij.openapi.application.impl.LaterInvocator$FlushQueue.runNextEvent(LaterInvocator.java:424)
    at com.intellij.openapi.application.impl.LaterInvocator$FlushQueue.run(LaterInvocator.java:407)
    at java.awt.event.InvocationEvent.dispatch(InvocationEvent.java:311)
    at java.awt.EventQueue.dispatchEventImpl(EventQueue.java:764)
    at java.awt.EventQueue.access$500(EventQueue.java:98)
    at java.awt.EventQueue$3.run(EventQueue.java:715)
    at java.awt.EventQueue$3.run(EventQueue.java:709)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at java.security.ProtectionDomain$JavaSecurityAccessImpl.doIntersectionPrivilege(ProtectionDomain.java:74)
    at java.awt.EventQueue.dispatchEvent(EventQueue.java:734)
    at com.intellij.ide.IdeEventQueue.defaultDispatchEvent(IdeEventQueue.java:908)
    at com.intellij.ide.IdeEventQueue._dispatchEvent(IdeEventQueue.java:781)
    at com.intellij.ide.IdeEventQueue.lambda$dispatchEvent$8(IdeEventQueue.java:424)
    at com.intellij.openapi.progress.impl.CoreProgressManager.computePrioritized(CoreProgressManager.java:687)
    at com.intellij.ide.IdeEventQueue.dispatchEvent(IdeEventQueue.java:423)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpOneEventForFilters(EventDispatchThread.java:205)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEventsForFilter(EventDispatchThread.java:116)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEventsForFilter(EventDispatchThread.java:109)
    at java.awt.WaitDispatchSupport$2.run(WaitDispatchSupport.java:190)
    at java.awt.WaitDispatchSupport$4.run(WaitDispatchSupport.java:235)
    at java.awt.WaitDispatchSupport$4.run(WaitDispatchSupport.java:233)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at java.awt.WaitDispatchSupport.enter(WaitDispatchSupport.java:233)
    at java.awt.Dialog.show(Dialog.java:1077)
    at com.intellij.openapi.ui.impl.DialogWrapperPeerImpl$MyDialog.show(DialogWrapperPeerImpl.java:708)
    at com.intellij.openapi.ui.impl.DialogWrapperPeerImpl.show(DialogWrapperPeerImpl.java:433)
    at com.intellij.openapi.ui.DialogWrapper.doShow(DialogWrapper.java:1698)
    at com.intellij.openapi.ui.DialogWrapper.show(DialogWrapper.java:1657)
    at com.intellij.openapi.progress.util.ProgressDialog.show(ProgressDialog.java:270)
    at com.intellij.openapi.progress.util.ProgressWindow.showDialog(ProgressWindow.java:211)
    at com.intellij.openapi.progress.util.ProgressWindow.lambda$null$1(ProgressWindow.java:144)
    at com.intellij.openapi.application.TransactionGuardImpl$2.run(TransactionGuardImpl.java:309)
    at com.intellij.openapi.application.impl.LaterInvocator$FlushQueue.doRun(LaterInvocator.java:441)
    at com.intellij.openapi.application.impl.LaterInvocator$FlushQueue.runNextEvent(LaterInvocator.java:424)
    at com.intellij.openapi.application.impl.LaterInvocator$FlushQueue.run(LaterInvocator.java:407)
    at java.awt.event.InvocationEvent.dispatch(InvocationEvent.java:311)
    at java.awt.EventQueue.dispatchEventImpl(EventQueue.java:764)
    at java.awt.EventQueue.access$500(EventQueue.java:98)
    at java.awt.EventQueue$3.run(EventQueue.java:715)
    at java.awt.EventQueue$3.run(EventQueue.java:709)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at java.security.ProtectionDomain$JavaSecurityAccessImpl.doIntersectionPrivilege(ProtectionDomain.java:74)
    at java.awt.EventQueue.dispatchEvent(EventQueue.java:734)
    at com.intellij.ide.IdeEventQueue.defaultDispatchEvent(IdeEventQueue.java:908)
    at com.intellij.ide.IdeEventQueue._dispatchEvent(IdeEventQueue.java:781)
    at com.intellij.ide.IdeEventQueue.lambda$dispatchEvent$8(IdeEventQueue.java:424)
    at com.intellij.openapi.progress.impl.CoreProgressManager.computePrioritized(CoreProgressManager.java:698)
    at com.intellij.ide.IdeEventQueue.dispatchEvent(IdeEventQueue.java:423)
    at com.intellij.ide.IdeEventQueue.pumpEventsForHierarchy(IdeEventQueue.java:965)
    at com.intellij.openapi.progress.util.ProgressWindow.startBlocking(ProgressWindow.java:186)
    at com.intellij.openapi.progress.util.ProgressWindow.startBlocking(ProgressWindow.java:172)
    at com.intellij.openapi.application.impl.ApplicationImpl.runProcessWithProgressSynchronously(ApplicationImpl.java:455)
    at com.intellij.openapi.progress.impl.CoreProgressManager.runProcessWithProgressSynchronously(CoreProgressManager.java:453)
    at com.intellij.openapi.progress.impl.ProgressManagerImpl.runProcessWithProgressSynchronously(ProgressManagerImpl.java:82)
    at com.intellij.openapi.progress.impl.CoreProgressManager.runProcessWithProgressSynchronously(CoreProgressManager.java:250)
    at com.intellij.openapi.progress.impl.CoreProgressManager.runProcessWithProgressSynchronously(CoreProgressManager.java:204)
    at com.intellij.openapi.project.impl.ProjectManagerImpl.loadProjectUnderProgress(ProjectManagerImpl.java:439)
    at com.intellij.openapi.project.impl.ProjectManagerImpl.lambda$openProject$5(ProjectManagerImpl.java:415)
    at com.intellij.openapi.application.TransactionGuardImpl.runSyncTransaction(TransactionGuardImpl.java:83)
    at com.intellij.openapi.application.TransactionGuardImpl.submitTransactionAndWait(TransactionGuardImpl.java:149)
    at com.intellij.openapi.project.impl.ProjectManagerImpl.openProject(ProjectManagerImpl.java:414)
    at com.android.tools.idea.npw.model.NewProjectModel$multiTemplateRenderer$1.invoke(NewProjectModel.kt:127)
    at com.android.tools.idea.npw.model.NewProjectModel$multiTemplateRenderer$1.invoke(NewProjectModel.kt:103)
    at com.android.tools.idea.npw.model.MultiTemplateRenderer.countDown(MultiTemplateRenderer.kt:128)
    at com.android.tools.idea.npw.model.MultiTemplateRenderer.skipRender(MultiTemplateRenderer.kt:116)
    at com.android.tools.idea.npw.model.RenderTemplateModel.handleSkipped(RenderTemplateModel.kt:128)
    at com.android.tools.idea.wizard.model.ModelWizard.handleFinished(ModelWizard.java:408)
    at com.android.tools.idea.wizard.model.ModelWizard.goForward(ModelWizard.java:330)
    at com.android.tools.idea.wizard.model.ModelWizardDialog$FinishAction.doAction(ModelWizardDialog.java:313)
    at com.intellij.openapi.ui.DialogWrapper$DialogWrapperAction.actionPerformed(DialogWrapper.java:1834)
    at javax.swing.AbstractButton.fireActionPerformed(AbstractButton.java:2022)
    at javax.swing.AbstractButton$Handler.actionPerformed(AbstractButton.java:2348)
    at javax.swing.DefaultButtonModel.fireActionPerformed(DefaultButtonModel.java:402)
    at javax.swing.DefaultButtonModel.setPressed(DefaultButtonModel.java:259)
    at javax.swing.plaf.basic.BasicButtonListener.mouseReleased(BasicButtonListener.java:252)
    at java.awt.Component.processMouseEvent(Component.java:6550)
    at javax.swing.JComponent.processMouseEvent(JComponent.java:3325)
    at java.awt.Component.processEvent(Component.java:6315)
    at java.awt.Container.processEvent(Container.java:2239)
    at java.awt.Component.dispatchEventImpl(Component.java:4899)
    at java.awt.Container.dispatchEventImpl(Container.java:2297)
    at java.awt.Component.dispatchEvent(Component.java:4721)
    at java.awt.LightweightDispatcher.retargetMouseEvent(Container.java:4904)
    at java.awt.LightweightDispatcher.processMouseEvent(Container.java:4535)
    at java.awt.LightweightDispatcher.dispatchEvent(Container.java:4476)
    at java.awt.Container.dispatchEventImpl(Container.java:2283)
    at java.awt.Window.dispatchEventImpl(Window.java:2746)
    at java.awt.Component.dispatchEvent(Component.java:4721)
    at java.awt.EventQueue.dispatchEventImpl(EventQueue.java:766)
    at java.awt.EventQueue.access$500(EventQueue.java:98)
    at java.awt.EventQueue$3.run(EventQueue.java:715)
    at java.awt.EventQueue$3.run(EventQueue.java:709)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at java.security.ProtectionDomain$JavaSecurityAccessImpl.doIntersectionPrivilege(ProtectionDomain.java:74)
    at java.security.ProtectionDomain$JavaSecurityAccessImpl.doIntersectionPrivilege(ProtectionDomain.java:84)
    at java.awt.EventQueue$4.run(EventQueue.java:739)
    at java.awt.EventQueue$4.run(EventQueue.java:737)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at java.security.ProtectionDomain$JavaSecurityAccessImpl.doIntersectionPrivilege(ProtectionDomain.java:74)
    at java.awt.EventQueue.dispatchEvent(EventQueue.java:736)
    at com.intellij.ide.IdeEventQueue.defaultDispatchEvent(IdeEventQueue.java:908)
    at com.intellij.ide.IdeEventQueue.dispatchMouseEvent(IdeEventQueue.java:846)
    at com.intellij.ide.IdeEventQueue._dispatchEvent(IdeEventQueue.java:778)
    at com.intellij.ide.IdeEventQueue.lambda$dispatchEvent$8(IdeEventQueue.java:424)
    at com.intellij.openapi.progress.impl.CoreProgressManager.computePrioritized(CoreProgressManager.java:687)
    at com.intellij.ide.IdeEventQueue.dispatchEvent(IdeEventQueue.java:423)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpOneEventForFilters(EventDispatchThread.java:205)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEventsForFilter(EventDispatchThread.java:116)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEventsForFilter(EventDispatchThread.java:109)
    at java.awt.WaitDispatchSupport$2.run(WaitDispatchSupport.java:190)
    at java.awt.WaitDispatchSupport$4.run(WaitDispatchSupport.java:235)
    at java.awt.WaitDispatchSupport$4.run(WaitDispatchSupport.java:233)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at java.awt.WaitDispatchSupport.enter(WaitDispatchSupport.java:233)
    at java.awt.Dialog.show(Dialog.java:1077)
    at com.intellij.openapi.ui.impl.DialogWrapperPeerImpl$MyDialog.show(DialogWrapperPeerImpl.java:708)
    at com.intellij.openapi.ui.impl.DialogWrapperPeerImpl.show(DialogWrapperPeerImpl.java:433)
    at com.intellij.openapi.ui.DialogWrapper.doShow(DialogWrapper.java:1698)
    at com.intellij.openapi.ui.DialogWrapper.show(DialogWrapper.java:1657)
    at com.android.tools.idea.actions.AndroidNewProjectAction.actionPerformed(AndroidNewProjectAction.kt:45)
    at com.intellij.openapi.actionSystem.ex.ActionUtil$1.run(ActionUtil.java:298)
    at com.intellij.openapi.actionSystem.ex.ActionUtil.performActionDumbAware(ActionUtil.java:315)
    at com.intellij.openapi.actionSystem.impl.ActionMenuItem$ActionTransmitter.lambda$actionPerformed$0(ActionMenuItem.java:293)
    at com.intellij.openapi.wm.impl.FocusManagerImpl.runOnOwnContext(FocusManagerImpl.java:263)
    at com.intellij.openapi.wm.impl.IdeFocusManagerImpl.runOnOwnContext(IdeFocusManagerImpl.java:77)
    at com.intellij.openapi.actionSystem.impl.ActionMenuItem$ActionTransmitter.actionPerformed(ActionMenuItem.java:282)
    at javax.swing.AbstractButton.fireActionPerformed(AbstractButton.java:2022)
    at com.intellij.openapi.actionSystem.impl.ActionMenuItem.lambda$fireActionPerformed$0(ActionMenuItem.java:110)
    at com.intellij.openapi.application.TransactionGuardImpl.runSyncTransaction(TransactionGuardImpl.java:83)
    at com.intellij.openapi.application.TransactionGuardImpl.lambda$submitTransaction$1(TransactionGuardImpl.java:107)
    at com.intellij.openapi.application.TransactionGuardImpl.submitTransaction(TransactionGuardImpl.java:116)
    at com.intellij.openapi.application.TransactionGuard.submitTransaction(TransactionGuard.java:121)
    at com.intellij.openapi.actionSystem.impl.ActionMenuItem.fireActionPerformed(ActionMenuItem.java:110)
    at com.intellij.ui.plaf.beg.BegMenuItemUI.doClick(BegMenuItemUI.java:517)
    at com.intellij.ui.plaf.beg.BegMenuItemUI.access$300(BegMenuItemUI.java:36)
    at com.intellij.ui.plaf.beg.BegMenuItemUI$MyMouseInputHandler.mouseReleased(BegMenuItemUI.java:539)
    at java.awt.Component.processMouseEvent(Component.java:6550)
    at javax.swing.JComponent.processMouseEvent(JComponent.java:3325)
    at java.awt.Component.processEvent(Component.java:6315)
    at java.awt.Container.processEvent(Container.java:2239)
    at java.awt.Component.dispatchEventImpl(Component.java:4899)
    at java.awt.Container.dispatchEventImpl(Container.java:2297)
    at java.awt.Component.dispatchEvent(Component.java:4721)
    at java.awt.LightweightDispatcher.retargetMouseEvent(Container.java:4904)
    at java.awt.LightweightDispatcher.processMouseEvent(Container.java:4535)
    at java.awt.LightweightDispatcher.dispatchEvent(Container.java:4476)
    at java.awt.Container.dispatchEventImpl(Container.java:2283)
    at java.awt.Window.dispatchEventImpl(Window.java:2746)
    at java.awt.Component.dispatchEvent(Component.java:4721)
    at java.awt.EventQueue.dispatchEventImpl(EventQueue.java:766)
    at java.awt.EventQueue.access$500(EventQueue.java:98)
    at java.awt.EventQueue$3.run(EventQueue.java:715)
    at java.awt.EventQueue$3.run(EventQueue.java:709)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at java.security.ProtectionDomain$JavaSecurityAccessImpl.doIntersectionPrivilege(ProtectionDomain.java:74)
    at java.security.ProtectionDomain$JavaSecurityAccessImpl.doIntersectionPrivilege(ProtectionDomain.java:84)
    at java.awt.EventQueue$4.run(EventQueue.java:739)
    at java.awt.EventQueue$4.run(EventQueue.java:737)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at java.security.ProtectionDomain$JavaSecurityAccessImpl.doIntersectionPrivilege(ProtectionDomain.java:74)
    at java.awt.EventQueue.dispatchEvent(EventQueue.java:736)
    at com.intellij.ide.IdeEventQueue.defaultDispatchEvent(IdeEventQueue.java:908)
    at com.intellij.ide.IdeEventQueue.dispatchMouseEvent(IdeEventQueue.java:846)
    at com.intellij.ide.IdeEventQueue._dispatchEvent(IdeEventQueue.java:778)
    at com.intellij.ide.IdeEventQueue.lambda$dispatchEvent$8(IdeEventQueue.java:424)
    at com.intellij.openapi.progress.impl.CoreProgressManager.computePrioritized(CoreProgressManager.java:698)
    at com.intellij.ide.IdeEventQueue.dispatchEvent(IdeEventQueue.java:423)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpOneEventForFilters(EventDispatchThread.java:205)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEventsForFilter(EventDispatchThread.java:116)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEventsForHierarchy(EventDispatchThread.java:105)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEvents(EventDispatchThread.java:101)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEvents(EventDispatchThread.java:93)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.run(EventDispatchThread.java:82)
```

No activity is created in the new project, and when I go to create a new activity, it doesn't give any error message, but no new activity shows up in the IDE or in the file explorer.

I'm running the latest version of Android Studio. I tried uninstalling everything and reinstalling it. Same problem. I tried installing a different SDK version and it still did this. Any help would be appreciated. Thanks!

Comment: try to reinstall latest version of android studio

Comment: Like I said in the post, I've reinstalled the whole thing 2 or 3 times.

Comment: Now is 2021, and this very same issue still exist. Not only gradle-wrapper.properties have wrong and incomplete content, but several xml file (e.g. activity layout file) is also corrupted. Reinstalling doesn't work, invalidate cache doesn't work.

Answer (score 0):

I met the same problem as you. I also opened the `gradle-wrapper.properties` and it seemed broken. So I opened another `gradle-wrapper.properties` created in my previous project, its content is:

```
#Fri Jul 31 11:47:56 CST 2020
distributionBase=GRADLE_USER_HOME
distributionPath=wrapper/dists
zipStoreBase=GRADLE_USER_HOME
zipStorePath=wrapper/dists
distributionUrl=https\://services.gradle.org/distributions/gradle-6.1.1-all.zip
```

make sure the gradle version is what you need.

Upd: I found although the build process was successful after editing the file, there was no default activity in directory `Java`, so I tried uninstalling the whole thing and reinstalling Android Studio in another place. It worked!